# How can I iterate over part of a hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

In a Rails environment i get a params hash from a form. 
Besides others, like

```
params[:vocab][:name] 
params[:vocab][:priority]
```

I have the 3 fields tag_1, tag_2, tag_3 whose values are stored in

```
params[:vocab][:tag_1] 
params[:vocab][:tag_2] 
params[:vocab][:tag_3]
```

My question is:
Can I iterate over these three hash keys? 
I want to do sth like

```
for i in 1..3 do
  iterator = ":tag_" + i.to_s
  puts params[:vocab][iterator.to_sym]
end
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: `params[:vocab].values.each {|x| puts x}` will also work

Comment: I think I need to make clearer that there are more key value pairs than just these three..will edit my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach doesn't work because:

```
':tag_2'.to_sym
# => :":tag_2"
```

so it would work if you remove leading colon from `":tag_" + i.to_s`

You can also do it this way, iterating over keys:

```
[:tag_1, :tag_2, :tag_3].each { |key| puts params[:vocab][key] }
```

Comment: Because it wouldn't just iterate over params[:vocab][:tag_1] params[:vocab][:tag_2] and params[:vocab][:tag_3] but also over all the other form fields.

Comment: That works, thanks a lot. But is there a more elegant way? Doesn't feel right somehow..

Answer (score 3):

You can construct symbols via interpolation; prefixing a string with a colon will cause Ruby to interpret it as a symbol.

```
(1..3).each do |i|
  puts params[:vocab][:"tag_#{i}"]
end
```